# New line and whitespace at the end of a string

Tags: python, printing, newline

#### Task

Write multiple if statements:

- If `car_year` is `1969` or earlier, print `"Few safety features."`
- If `1970` or later, print `"Probably has seat belts."`
- If `1990` or later, print `"Probably has antilock brakes."`
- If `2000` or later, print `"Probably has airbags."`

End each phrase with a *period* and a *newline*.

#### Sample output

For input: 1995

```
Probably has seat belts.
Probably has antilock brakes.
```

#### Code

```
car_year = int(input())

if car_year <=1969:
    message='Few safety features'
    print(message+'.''\n')
if car_year >=1970:
    message1='Probably has seat belts'
    print(message1+'.''\n')
if car_year >=1990:
    message2='Probably has antilock brakes'
    print(message2+'.''\n')
if car_year >=2000:
    message3='Probably has airbags'
    print(message3+'.''\n')
```

#### Problem

This is what I was getting originally:

- two new-lines after the sentence (2nd highlighted in the image)

[image: two new-lines after the sentence]

After trying a few solutions I keep getting this:

- a space after the sentence (highlighted in the image)

[image: a space after the sentence]

Sorry for the terrible explanation.
I'm new to coding and don't know how to explain exactly what I'm thinking.

Comment: Do you know what `\n` means?

Comment: Yes, it's the new line command. I thought I had a pretty good understanding of it, but I see that it's not as simple as I once thought

Comment: You seem to know the backslash-escaped control-character for new-line (`\n`). What you probably missed is [`print`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print) function has default-parameter `end='\n'` which adds a new-line after the printed string by default unless specified other.

Answer (score 4):

You are adding a newline (`\n`) to the string, but `print` automatically adds a single newline after the string, so you get two newlines in total. Just remove the `\n`s to get a single newline (the one automatically added by `print`).

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `end` attribute of the print function for this

```py
car_year = int(input())

if car_year <=1969:
    message='Few safety features'
    print(message+'.', end=" ")
if car_year >=1970:
    message1='Probably has seat belts'
    print(message1+'.', end="")
if car_year >=1990:
    message2='Probably has antilock brakes'
    print(message2+'.', end=" ")
if car_year >=2000:
    message3='Probably has airbags'
    print(message3+'.', end=" ")
```

Comment: Although your code deviates from expected output, explain what it does (e.g. "prints the messages separated by a single space instead of a newline"). One statement is inconsistent in the end: `print(message1+'.', end="")`.

Comment: @hc_dev Thanks for pointing it out; the question wasn't phrased correctly when I had wrote my answer, it made me believe the requirement was using `end=" "`.

Answer (score 1):

Solving the task step by step (iterative):

#### (1) implement all conditional cases (4 if-statements)

```py
car_year = int(input())

if car_year <= 1969:
    print('Few safety features')
if car_year >= 1970:
    print('Probably has seat belts')
if car_year >= 1990:
    print('Probably has antilock brakes')
if car_year >= 2000:
    print('Probably has airbags')
```

Note some stylistic improvements and simplifications:

1. surround operands by spaces to improve readability, for example

   instead `less=x<1` prefer `better = x > 1`
2. inline the strings/variables when only used once, for example

   instead `message1 = constant; print(constant)` prefer `print('constant')`
3. start simple (KISS), for example:

   instead early optimization of format (period plus space at the end) start with `print('phrase')` and solve formatting in later iteration

#### (2) implement the formatting (how each phrase should end)

Read the docs about Python's built-in [`print`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print) function:

> `print(*objects, sep=' ', end='\n', file=sys.stdout, flush=False)`
>
> Print *objects* to the text stream *file*, separated by *sep* and followed by ***end***.

Considerations:

1. instead `message+'.', end=" "` like suggested by [Avijeet's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70792028/5730279) you can simply specify the whole terminating suffix as required: `end='.\n'` (period followed by newline).
2. optional: keep it configurable at a central place with a variable `phrase_end = '.\n'`

```py
phrase_end = '.\n'  # specify the required end

car_year = int(input())

if car_year <= 1969:
    print('Few safety features', end=phrase_end)  # add the argument; for each 
if car_year >= 1970:
    print('Probably has seat belts', end=phrase_end)
if car_year >= 1990:
    print('Probably has antilock brakes', end=phrase_end)
if car_year >= 2000:
    print('Probably has airbags', end=phrase_end)
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove \n from the line print(message1+'.''\n')
also from the line print(message2+'.''\n')